# Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate return this error Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Maximum retry attempts 10, has be attempted

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have a communication site collection inside our SharePoint online tenant. and i want to export this site and create a new site based on the exported template, so i run this command:-

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://***.com/sites/Filing/
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out template.pnp
```

but i got this error:-

> Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Maximum retry attempts 10, has be
>   attempted. At line:1 char:1 + Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Out
>   template.pnp + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate],
>   MaximumRetryAttemptedException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Provisioning.Site.GetProvisioningTemplate

Answer (score 1):

This error might have come due to the **throttling**  so you can try increasing the value  of **RetryCount** parameter

Example :

```
Invoke-PnPQuery -RetryCount 10
```

Notes :

- The error what you are getting now, you may not get after sometimes, because throttling error comes when resource utilization in the target connection is high and this is not fixed, this gets fluctuated. So, you can try again after sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how and where i need to add this script? before running my script?

Comment: Try to add the RetryCount parameter in the Connect-PnPOnline, if not found there Chek in PnP provisioning command if doesn't work there also, try to add indepdently before your script.

Comment: Even you can write in the middle of PnP connect online and provisioning... you may refer to this URL :https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.erwinmcm.com/getting-started-with-the-office-365-developer-patterns-and-practices-powershell-cmdlets/amp/